# Custom Report in Dynamics CRM Online - Default Date Parameter

Tags: dynamics-crm, business-intelligence, microsoft-dynamics

I am creating a custom report for Dynamics CRM in Business Intelligence Devlopment Studio.
I have a filter in my FETCHXML with a date 'on-or-after' and the value as a date parameter.

When I don't set a default value, this worked fine however is causing the same error as below when I try to return to it, I have my date picker and could run the report from there.
I want to set a default as 1 month ago, so I put the following default expression into the parameter:

```
=DateAdd("M",-1,Today())
```

But I get the following error:

```
The date-time format for 18/04/2012 00:00:00 is invalid, or value is outside the supported range.
```

I'm assuming the date-time format is invalid for the `createdon` field in Dynamics but I don't know how it should be presented in the default value.

Answer (score 0):

MS Dynamics CRM 2011 uses SortableDateTi­mePattern.

So, I guess need to have it in this format: *yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss* (2008-03-09T16:05:07).

At least, I use it like this creating SOAP requests from JS.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response. I've used `=FORMAT(DateAdd("M",-1,Today()),"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")` but unfortunately get the error `The property 'DefaultValue' of report parameter 'date' doesn't have the expected type.`

Comment: Try to put your formula in dataset and put the default value for the parameter from it.
I did it in SSRS, maybe it'll work for you in FETCHXML.